# Force (or ask nicely) Linker To Link Away Specific Assembly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, linker, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Currently I have my Xamarin iOS and Xamarin Android project's linker setting set to 'Link Framework SDKs Only'. One day I will make the leap over to 'Link All', but until then, I would like to know if there is a way to have the linker, in addition to linking Framework SDKs, link a single project or assembly.

I know there are ways to exclude assemblies but can I do the opposite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to add:

```
[assembly: Foundation.LinkerSafe]
```

inside your assembly.

The linker will interpret this as a sign (from the code's author) that it's safe to process that assembly.

Another, more complex, way (that you're likely away but to make the answer more complete) is to use *Link all* and then use `--linkskip=X` on each assembly `X` that is not safe to link.

Comment: I guess I had heard about that annotation but only ever thought about it being used on plugins, but I guess they are no different that any other project's code. Really appreciate your help with this! Time to fight linker issues.